# javascript split() using regEx

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to split "A//B/C" string using javascript `split()` function

```
"A//B/C".split(/\//g)
```

but it's output is `["A", "", "B", "C"]`but my expected output is

```
["A/", "B", "C"]
```

how i do this using javascript ?

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag with split, it splits on every occurrence by default.

Comment: You can try `"A//B/C".split(/\//).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: "A//B/C".split(/\//) gives ["A", "", "B", "C"] @RobG

Comment: @Tushar in need A/ in first index

Comment: @lintocheeran—exactly, you don't need the `g`. It's a comment, not an answer. ;-)

Comment: Why do you expect `["A/", "B", "C"]`? Please explain why the first `/` shouldn't produce a split.

Comment: what should your regex match i case of "A/" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I updated @Tushar answer and tried this an it works out for me..added `\b` to match just the **forward slashes** followed by a **word boundary** e.g.,  [a-z] and [0-9]

```
"A//B/C".split(/\/\b/)
```

Comment: `\b` matches a [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), it seems that `/` by itself is a boundary, but `/` followed by `/` is not a boundary since the first `/` isn't a word character. Interesting.

Comment: yes it seems it works that way. since first forward slash is a word boundary itself just like what you've said :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `RegExp` `/\/(?=[A-Z]|$)/` to match `/` if followed by `A-Z` or end of input

```
"A//B/C".split(/\/(?=[A-Z]|$)/)
```

Comment: "A//B/C/".split(/\/(?=[A-Z]|$)/) gives ["A/", "B", "C", ""] but "A//B/C/".split(/\/\b/) gives ["A/", "B", "C/"]

Comment: @lintocheeran Yes. What is expected result? `"A//B/C/"` does not appear at nor is expected result of `"A//B/C/"` described at Question?

Comment: sorry i expecting pattern not static one

Comment: @lintocheeran _"sorry i am expect pattern not static one"_ ? What do you mean by "pattern"? What is pattern? What do you mean by "not static one"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string at a position, where the current character is "/" and the following character is not "/". However, the second (negative) condition should not be consumed by the regex. In other words: It shouldn't be regarded as delimeter. For this you can use a so called "look ahead". There is a positive "look ahead" and a negative one. Here we need a negative one, since we want to express "not followed by". The syntax is: `(?!<string>)`, whereas  is what shouldn't 'follow'.

So there you go: `/\/(?!\/)/`

**applied to your example:**

```
"A//B/C".split(/\/(?!\/)/); // ["A/", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: "A//B/C/".split(/\/(?!\/)/); giving ["A/", "B", "C", ""] it's not match pattern like [A-Z]/

Comment: right, I asked the OP how to handle this case. If "A/" should result i ["A/"], then my answer is incorrect and the word boundary propose is the way to go. or similarly this would work: /\/(?=[^/])/